# Use git submodules for external repositories without use password inside .gitmodules file

Tags: git, git-submodules

I'm using a repository in gitlab,

This repository have two submodules, one of them also in gitlab, but another one is in bitbucket.

Now I have inside `.gitmodules` file this content:

```
[submodule "src/repo"]
    path = src/repo
    url = https://ruimartins:***password***@bitbucket.org/xxxxxx/repo.git
[submodule "helm-chart"]
    path = helm-chart
    url = ../helm-chart.git
```

But I don't want to have the password visible to all programmers, how can I hide the password from here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to replace the credential based access to a token based access such as ssh. So you can replace the url with `url = git@bitbucket.org:xxxxxx/repo.git`. Then just create a group or team where you give other users access to this code. It is a better approach to authenticate via the individual user rather than sharing some credentials.

With this approach it won't be required to change to ssh authentication as the individual user can authenticate with its own credentials. However I would strongly recommend to use a token based authentication.

For instance, github already announced to disable credential based authentication in the next year as they are less secure compared to token based authentication